# Code is run before the javascript is done successfully

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

I am scraping a web page with the use of python selenium library, trying to extract data from a table here at this link:

```
url = 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/2018-2019/2018-2019-Premier-League-Stats'
wd = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path='C:\\Users\\erics\\Downloads\\Chrome Driver\\chromedriver.exe')
wd.get(url)
```

in my next cell - it's a Jupyter notebook environment, I have the following code:

```
wd.maximize_window()
wd.execute_script("""var l = document.getElementsByClassName("adblock stn")[0]; l.parentNode.removeChild(l);""")
seasonTable = wd.find_element_by_class_name("table_wrapper")
wd.execute_script("return arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", seasonTable)
```

so far, everything runs perfectly. Table gets into viewpoint and I can extract the data from the second tab of the table - Home/Away - with the following code:

```
homeAwayTable = WebDriverWait(wd, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.LINK_TEXT, "Home/Away")))
homeAwayTable.click()
```

problem is when I put all these lines in one cell as I want to create a function. When all lines are in the same cell, I get this error:

*ElementClickInterceptedException: Message: element click intercepted: Element is not clickable at point (165, 1518)*

I believe this is because somehow the javascript code is not done yet, and next line of code is run. I tried adding explicit waits after javascript code, but still I'm getting the same error.
Would you please help me solve this issue?

Answer (score 1):

Just in case you were not aware, there is a less complex way of obtaining that data:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

url= 'https://fbref.com/en/comps/9/2018-2019/2018-2019-Premier-League-Stats'
dfs = pd.read_html(requests.get(url).text.replace('<!--', '').replace('-->', ''), header=1)
display(dfs[1])
```

Result:

```
Rk  Squad   MP  W   D   L   GF  GA  GD  Pts Pts/MP  xG  xGA xGD xGD/90  MP.1    W.1 D.1 L.1 GF.1    GA.1    GD.1    Pts.1   Pts/MP.1    xG.1    xGA.1   xGD.1   xGD/90.1
0   1   Manchester City 19  18  0   1   57  12  45  54  2.84    48.9    13.8    35.1    1.85    19  14  2   3   38  11  27  44  2.32    35.7    11.3    24.4    1.28
1   2   Liverpool   19  17  2   0   55  10  45  53  2.79    43.5    13.9    29.6    1.56    19  13  5   1   34  12  22  44  2.32    31.8    17.0    14.8    0.78
2   3   Chelsea 19  12  6   1   39  12  27  42  2.21    31.3    14.5    16.8    0.88    19  9   3   7   24  27  -3  30  1.58    27.7    21.2    6.4 0.34
3   4   Tottenham   19  12  2   5   34  16  18  38  2.00    33.3    24.3    9.0 0.47    19  11  0   8   33  23  10  33  1.74    25.3    21.6    3.7 0.19
4   5   Arsenal 19  14  3   2   42  16  26  45  2.37    34.5    22.5    12.0    0.63    19  7   4   8   31  35  -4  25  1.32    24.5    31.6    -7.0    -0.37
5   6   Manchester Utd  19  10  6   3   33  25  8   36  1.89    31.3    19.9    11.4    0.60    19  9   3   7   32  29  3   30  1.58    27.5    26.2    1.2 0.06
6   7   Wolves  19  10  4   5   28  21  7   34  1.79    28.7    17.0    11.7    0.61    19  6   5   8   19  25  -6  23  1.21    19.5    21.7    -2.2    -0.11
7   8   Everton 19  10  4   5   30  21  9   34  1.79    26.9    22.7    4.3 0.22    19  5   5   9   24  25  -1  20  1.05    21.3    24.8    -3.4    -0.18
8   9   Leicester City  19  8   3   8   24  20  4   27  1.42    25.5    20.1    5.4 0.29    19  7   4   8   27  28  -1  25  1.32    24.0    25.3    -1.3    -0.07
9   10  West Ham    19  9   4   6   32  27  5   31  1.63    25.7    24.5    1.2 0.07    19  6   3   10  20  28  -8  21  1.11    22.0    36.4    -14.4   -0.76
10  11  Watford 19  8   3   8   26  28  -2  27  1.42    22.9    27.5    -4.6    -0.24   19  6   5   8   26  31  -5  23  1.21    24.6    27.1    -2.5    -0.13
11  12  Crystal Palace  19  5   5   9   19  23  -4  20  1.05    28.1    22.6    5.5 0.29    19  9   2   8   32  30  2   29  1.53    22.3    26.0    -3.7    -0.19
12  13  Newcastle Utd   19  8   1   10  24  25  -1  25  1.32    22.9    23.3    -0.4    -0.02   19  4   8   7   18  23  -5  20  1.05    15.9    29.4    -13.6   -0.71
13  14  Bournemouth 19  8   5   6   30  25  5   29  1.53    28.0    24.3    3.7 0.19    19  5   1   13  26  45  -19 16  0.84    26.1    31.5    -5.3    -0.28
14  15  Burnley 19  7   2   10  24  32  -8  23  1.21    23.7    26.9    -3.3    -0.17   19  4   5   10  21  36  -15 17  0.89    17.1    37.2    -20.1   -1.06
15  16  Southampton 19  5   8   6   27  30  -3  23  1.21    24.3    25.0    -0.7    -0.04   19  4   4   11  18  35  -17 16  0.84    23.2    30.7    -7.5    -0.39
16  17  Brighton    19  6   5   8   19  28  -9  23  1.21    20.4    22.7    -2.4    -0.12   19  3   4   12  16  32  -16 13  0.68    14.0    33.4    -19.5   -1.02
17  18  Cardiff City    19  6   2   11  21  38  -17 20  1.05    23.4    26.2    -2.8    -0.15   19  4   2   13  13  31  -18 14  0.74    15.9    36.2    -20.3   -1.07
18  19  Fulham  19  6   3   10  22  36  -14 21  1.11    22.6    28.0    -5.3    -0.28   19  1   2   16  12  45  -33 5   0.26    16.2    38.6    -22.4   -1.18
19  20  Huddersfield    19  2   3   14  10  31  -21 9   0.47    15.5    28.7    -13.2   -0.69   19  1   4   14  12  45  -33 7   0.37    14.0    34.3    -20.3   -1.07
```

Pandas documentation can be found here: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/

Also requests documentation: https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: This is awesome. Thank you. However, this is a project that I have to run with the help of Selenium.

Comment: What is your ultimate goal? Is this a school assignment? @EricSaboori

Comment: Not for school. I've defined it for myself to get hands-on experience with Selenium. I'm practicing. Not much of experience in this field. I want to collect all data of the final table season for the last 20 years of the premier league.

Comment: Selenium is a testing tool, meant to be used in Q&A, Automation. Web scraping is a different field, and Selenium is the last resort for scraping a website, if all else fails (scrapy, requests, httpx, scrapy-playwright, etc). As a suggestion, to avoid that error, you can first bring that element into view with `element.location_once_scrolled_into_view`, then click on it. @EricSaboori

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I was not aware of it.